# Internal Server Error calling a Datasnap server using Indy

Tags: delphi, indy, datasnap

I have set up a very basic DataSnap Server Application (Delphi XE3), containing the 2 sample methods, EchoString and ReverseString. I have added authentication so that only if the user calling the method is called "standard", they have access to the ReverseString method.

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);
begin
  valid := (User <> '');

  if (SameText(User, 'standard') = True) then
  begin
    UserRoles.Add('standard');
  end;
end;

type
TServerMethods1 = class(TDSServerModule)
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
  function EchoString(Value: string): string;
  [TRoleAuth('standard')]
  function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
end;
```

If I call this method from a browser directly, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/TestFromBrowser
```

then I get the expected response (after the browser's default login prompt, in which I enter an invalid user, e.g. Jason):

```
{"error":"jason is not authorized to perform the requested action."}
```

However, if I call it from a Delphi client application using Indy (TIdHTTP):

```
IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
IdHTTP1.Request.Username := 'jason';
IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'jason';

Label2.Caption := IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/TestFromDelphi');
```

I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

How can I avoid the error and receive the same RESTful response that I got in the browser? I have been trying to figure out how to view the HTTP request sent by the browser vs that sent by Indy but haven't managed it, even using Ethereal.

Comment: to capture requests and responses you can use Fiddler 2 as a HTTP proxy

Comment: Or Wireshark (the successor to Ethereal), since the connection is not using SSL.  If you use Fiddler, you have to configure the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property accordingly so `TIdHTTP` will connect to Fiddler.

Comment: What HTTP authentication scheme(s) does the DataSnap server support?  `BasicAuthentication := True` allows `TIdHTTP` to fallback to the `BASIC` scheme if no other authentication is used. What values are being reported in the `AuthInfo` parameter of the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event? That will tell you which schemes the server supports (if you cannot see it in Wireshark/Fiddler). `TIdHTTP` uses a plugin architecture for HTTP authentication, so make sure have added the relevant `IdAuthentication...` units to your `uses` clause for each scheme you want to enable.

Comment: Thanks Remy, will take a further look. Datasnap only supports Basic authentication as far as I have read, which is fine for the purpose I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to establish what is going on. Using Wireshark and Rawcap (to capture local loopback requests), I can see that even though the browser is showing the meaningful message:

```
{"error":"jason is not authorized to perform the requested action."}
```

it is also returning an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. However, the meaningful response text is also returned as part of this response, which is being displayed by the browser.

[image: Response from Browser]

Checking the Indy HTTP response, it is the same; the actual response code is a 500, but the text I want to display is also being returned.

[image]

This is accessible by capturing the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` and accessing its `ErrorMessage` property.